# Why do I get EOFError error when trying to read MNIST data?

Tags: python, pybrain

```
import cPickle, gzip, numpy

data = cPickle.load(gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb'))
trndata=data['train']
tstdata=data['test']
```

I was getting this error when I was running this code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):      
File "/home/converge_2_min/trainer.py", line 12, in <module>        
data = cPickle.load(gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb'))    
EOFError
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right and **complete** `mnist.pkl.gz`? I've just ran your code and didn't get any error unpickling the file.

Comment: You should link the source of your data.

Comment: You could also simply go through the original dataset: http://martin-thoma.com/classify-mnist-with-pybrain/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Cygwin and anaconda on windows.
Here is my pkl file (Cygwin)
$ md5sum mnist.pkl.gz
a02cd19f81d51c426d7ca14024243ce9 *mnist.pkl.gz

Unzipped:
$ md5sum mnist.pkl
533096469a4f4dbb70a78fdee468939a *mnist.pkl

On Ubuntu:
$ md5sum mnist.pkl
533096469a4f4dbb70a78fdee468939a  mnist.pkl

So it seems to be an issue with cPickle on windows-based python installs.